# Set temporary variables for current logged in user in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, session, authentication, codex

If my user can login from different browsers, concurrently, how can I save a temporary variable (a special format random variable or a device specific id) for each session and access it later in codex?

I can't use update_user_meta and get_user_meta, because user meta is user based, not session based.

Answer (score -1):

You could use user meta.

See [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

The current user id can be retrieved with [get_current_user_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) to set and then get values associated with a given user.

The only gotcha is when using get_user_meta (or any other get meta function in WordPress), is be sure to set `$single` to `true`, otherwise you'll get an array with just one value.

Comment: user meta is user dependent, not session dependent.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve? Provided the user is logged in on each device, I can't see what could be done with sessions that couldn't be done with user meta.